# Blender, Problems with normal map

Tags: texturing, lighting, normal-map

I have a plane (w/ texture and normal map) & a sphere (acting as a light source):

Here it is w/o the normal map:
[image: "w/o the normal map"]

Here it is w/ normal map:
[image: "w/ normal map"]

Normal map was created with [Materialize](http://boundingboxsoftware.com/materialize/) by Bounding Box Software.

Why on earth does the one with the Normal Map look as though either the light is directional or that the plane is tilted? <s>Is this a problem with the principled shader?</s> It is not, in fact, the principled shader; I just tested that while typing this.

So yeah, what is going on here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have fixed the problem. It was a simple need for a Normal Map Node:

[image: w/ Normal Map Node]

I kind of feel silly now, but you live and learn.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but just adding the normal map node didn't help. Changing Color Space from sRGB to XYZ in normal map node fixed the problem for me.